# lldb cannot lookup symbol in imported dylib

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, lldb

I am debugging a C program on arm64 with lldb and in order to implement my own debugging function I wrote a standalone debug helper program, compiled it as a dylib and imported it into lldb by using:

`(lldb) target modules add debugHelper.dylib`

However when I call the function declared in the dylib, lldb errors:

```
(lldb) expression debugPrint()
 error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
 _debugPrint
```

If I type in a random function name (e.g. foo):

```
(lldb) expression foo()
error: use of undeclared identifier 'foo'
```

, which makes me believe importing the dylib is indeed successful, since `debugPrint` is not an `undeclared identifier`.

---

```
// debugHelper.c

#include <stdio.h>


int debugPrint() {
    printf("%s\n", "Debug info printed! \n");
    return 0;
}
```

debugHelper.dylib is compiled with:

```
$ xcrun --sdk iphoneos cc debugHelper.c -o debugHelper.dylib -dynamiclib -arch arm64 -g
```

I also verified with `nm` that debugHelper.dylib does have the `_debugPrint` symbol:

```
$ nm debugHelper.dylib
0000000000007f2c T _debugPrint
                 U _printf
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

Results of `(lldb) image list` :

```
[263]... debugHelper.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/debugHelper.dylib
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`target modules add` loads the binary (and its dSYM, if there is one) into lldb's pool of binaries it knows about.  But the dylib has not been loaded into your inferior process -- you will not be able to run the functions in there.

Instead, run `dlopen()` in your process:

```
(lldb) p (int)dlopen("debugHelper.dylib", 10)
```

(that 10 is `RTLD_GLOBAL|RTLD_NOW`, v. `dlfcn.h`).  There's also an SB API method to do this, `SBProcess::LoadImage` which doesn't require you to look up the details of `dlopen`.  e.g.

```
(lldb) script lldb.process.LoadImage(lldb.SBFileSpec("debugHelper.dylib", False), lldb.SBError())
```